# How do I resolve a Hunspell Intel 32bit DLL not found exception? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, hunspell

I have used the following code for spelling checking.

While I am running it, I get an `DLLFileNotFound` exception:

> "Hunspell Intel 32Bit DLL not found: C:\project\splee\Hunspellx86.dll".

#### Code Snippet:

```
using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic")) 
    { 
        bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation"); 
        var suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendation"); 
        foreach (string suggestion in suggestions) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Suggestion is: " + suggestion); 
        } 
    } 

    // Hyphen 
    using (Hyphen hyphen = new Hyphen("hyph_en_us.dic")) 
    { 
        var hyphenated = hyphen.Hyphenate("Recommendation"); 
    } 


    using (MyThes thes = new MyThes("th_en_us_new.idx", "th_en_us_new.dat")) 
    { 
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic")) 
        { 
            ThesResult tr = thes.Lookup("cars", hunspell); 
            foreach (ThesMeaning meaning in tr.Meanings) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("  Meaning: " + meaning.Description); 
                foreach (string synonym in meaning.Synonyms) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("    Synonym: " + synonym); 

                } 
            } 
        }
```

I have made a reference to `Hunspell.dll` in the project. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the native `Hunspellx86.dll` next to the the managed `NHunspell.dll`.

I did the following way:

1. Referenced `NHunspell`.
2. set the Copy Local property
3. Include the `NHunspellx86.dll` to my project
4. Set "Copy to output directory" property "copy if newer".

This ensures that the native Hunspell.dll will be in place.

Comment: This is only a useful solution in the situation where it is verified that the NHunspellx** DLL is not in the correct place (in the bin folder). In my case, the DLL is definitely in place correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I have replicated this error in two different scenarios using NHunspell v 0.9.4. It appears that NHunspell shows this error message for a range of issues which could occur during the process of loading the relevant unmanaged Hunspellx**.dll.

The first cause I found was if the particular IIS app pool running my webapp did not have 32-bit applications enabled. This, of course, is only relevant if you're running your 32-bit webapp on a 64-bit machine.

The second cause I found was if the IIS process user did not have appropriate permissions to read the folder containing Hunspellx**.dll. The IIS users (group called something like MACHINENAME\IIS_IUSRS) must have permission to read and execute every file in the webapp execution directory (and bin subfolder).

Comment: Thanks for tips - Had the same issue, but the IIS process needs read access to the directory. However, changing 32bit webapps enabled did not resolve the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the Copy local setting is set to "Copy always" when you right click the NHunspell.DLL in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this in VB.net 2010 as follows, I assume something similar can be done in C# and later versions of VB.net:

1. Double-click "My Project" in Solution Explorer.
2. Click the "View Application Events" button.
3. Add an Application Startup event like this:

> ```
>  Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
>      Hunspell.NativeDllPath = "D:\VB.net\_system\hunspell\dll\" '(replace path with folder containing Hunspellx86.dll)
>  End Sub
> ```

I believe you can also just put Hunspellx86.dll in the folder containing your application's .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a production environment when the version of the unmanaged DLLs was slightly older than the version the ASP.Net project was built against.

Specifically FusLogVw showed:

```
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\ThePath\Hunspellx64.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

Updating to the correct version of the unmanaged DLLs resolved the issue.